# How do I change the line color in Altair's Filled Step chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, altair, vega-lite

I am working directly on the [example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/filled_step_chart.html) from the docs.
I changed the fill color to red and I also want to change the line color, but it stays `blue` no matter what I do. I tried changing `fill`, `stroke` and `color` to `red`, but the line still stays `blue`.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

alt.Chart(source).mark_area(
    color="red",
    fill="red",
    interpolate='step-after',
    line=True
).encode(
    x='date',
    y='price'
).transform_filter(alt.datum.symbol == 'GOOG')
```

[image]

Am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `color='red'` or `stroke='red'` should work, but doesn't: this is probably a bug in Vega or Vega-Lite. But you can work around it by setting the color encoding to a value:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

alt.Chart(source).mark_area(
    fill="red",
    interpolate='step-after',
    line=True
).encode(
    x='date',
    y='price',
    color=alt.value('red')
).transform_filter(alt.datum.symbol == 'GOOG')
```

[image]